# Reading an array from a text file in Common Lisp

Tags: arrays, file, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to read data (which is actually an array) in Lisp from a text file.
I tried to use `with-open-file` and `read-line` stuff but could not achieve my goal.  What I am looking for is equivalent to doing `data=load('filename.txt')` in MATLAB, so that I get an array called `data` which has loaded the whole information in `filename.txt`.

The text file will be in a format like

```
1.0 2.0 3.0 ...
1.5 2.5 3.5 ...
2.0 3.0 4.0 ...
 .....
```

The size may also vary. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic way to do that is to use `with-open-file` for getting the input stream, `read-line` in a `loop` to get the lines, `split-sequence` (from the library of the same name) to split it into fields, and `parse-number` (from the library of the same name) to transform the strings into numbers.  All libraries mentioned are available from [Quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org).

EDIT: Just to get you started, this is a simple version without validation:

```
(defun load-array-from-file (filename)
  (with-open-file (in filename
                      :direction :input)
    (let* ((data-lol (loop :for line := (read-line in nil)
                           :while line
                           :collect (mapcar #'parse-number:parse-number
                                            (cl-ppcre:split "\\s+" line))))
           (rows (length data-lol))
           (columns (length (first data-lol))))
      (make-array (list rows columns)
                  :initial-contents data-lol))))
```

You should add some checks and think about what you want to get in case they are not fulfilled:

- Are the rows all the same length?
- Are all fields valid numbers?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your file follows the formatting pattern you gave in your question: a sequence of numbers separated with white spaces, this is a quick snippet that should do what you want.

```
(defun read-array (filename)
  (with-open-file (in filename)
    (loop for num = (read in nil)
          until (null num)
          collect num)))
```

Comment: Using the reader for parsing user input is usually not a good idea.

Comment: @Svante: Where's the problem if the same user that's running the program is also providing the data?

Comment: @Rörd: A program/system can only securely differentiate between what is outside or inside of itself.  It should not speculate about things happening on the outside.

Comment: @Svante: OK, but that rule doesn't determine the boundaries of the system. If all the input data is going to be produced by an user who would have the necessary privileges to run arbitrary code anyway, I still don't really see the problem with a "quick and dirty" solution.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to leverage the lisp reader to parse the data in the text file. To do this, I'd probably convert the entire file into a string first, and then call

```
(eval (read-from-string (format nil "~a~a~a" "(initial wrapper code " str ")")))
```

For example, if you wanted to read in a data file that is all numbers, delimited by whitespace/newlines, into a list, the previous command would look like:

```
(eval (read-from-string (format nil "~a~a~a" "(list " str ")")))
```

Answer (score 2):

I followed Svante's advice. I just needed a single column in the text file, this is what I am using for this purpose.

```
(defun load_data (arr column filename)
(setf lnt (first (array-dimensions arr)))
 (with-open-file (str (format nil "~A.txt" filename) :direction :input)
   (loop :for i :from 0 :to (1- lnt) :do
       (setf (aref arr i 0) (read-from-string (nth (1- column) (split-sequence:SPLIT-SEQUENCE #\Space (read-line str))))))))
```

Thank you all for your help.